# How do I get cell row and column indexes of UWP Grid control?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I've been trying to get the row index and the column index when specific cell of grid control is tapped. So far nothing...

I achieved to take the absolute value of X and Y when I tap somewhere on the grid control.

```
private void gridGameBoard_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grd = sender as Grid;
    Point pos = e.GetPosition(grd);
}
```

I've tried this:

```
int row = Grid.GetColumn(grd);
int col = Grid.GetRow(grd);
```

Both gives me only zeros no matter where I tap.

I didn't find another way to take the row and column indexes of the tapped cell...

XAML code:

```
<Grid Background="Firebrick">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Name="gridGameBoard" Tapped="gridGameBoard_Tapped">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- # # # COLUMN 0 # # # -->
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/box.png" Height="51" Width="69" />
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="img00" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />

        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/box.png" Height="51" Width="69" />
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="img01" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />

        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/box.png" Height="51" Width="69" />
        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Name="img02" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />

        <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/box.png" Height="51" Width="69" />
        <Image Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Name="img03" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />

        <Image Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/box.png" Height="51" Width="69" />
        <Image Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Name="img04" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />

        <Image Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/box.png" Height="51" Width="69" />
        <Image Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Name="img05" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />

        <!-- # # # COLUMN 1 - 6 are same as COLUMN 0 # # # -->

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Grid.GetColumn(grd);`

```
 private void gridGameBoard_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Grid grd = sender as Grid;
             int i =    Grid.GetColumn(grd);//To get column no
             Grid.GetRow(grd);//To get row no
            }
```

Comment: Archana,

Thank you for the fast replay.
But I forgot to mention that I've tried this
`int row = Grid.GetColumn(grd);`
and
`int col = Grid.GetRow(grd);`.
Both gives me only zeros no matter where I tap.

Comment: It is giving correct values. Your grid is in 0th row and 0th column

Comment: Do you want to fetch Column value of controls INSIDE the Grid?

Comment: So this way I am getting the row and column in wich my child grid (gridGameBoard) is placed relevant to my parent grid (wich have no name)? If so how can then I get the row and the column indexes of the child grid (gridGameBoard) when I tap some cell? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must I get the child element of the grid in the specific cell and then use `Grid.GetColumn(childElement)` to take te right column and row indexes?

Comment: For example if you want to fetch row and column no of first cell you have to register tap event for that particular cell not its parent(gridGameBoard), which means you have  to add tap event for all your Image controls

Comment: Yup. But its difficult to get child element of tapped region,Instead add tap event for child elements like i said in previous comment

Comment: Ok thanks again. I will give it a try some time later and let you know the result.

Comment: Thank you for the help Archana. It works perfectly. I will update the question providing the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

### Many thanks to Arcana.

#### The solution is:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/img.png"  Tapped="image_Tapped" />

private void image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;

    int row = Grid.GetRow(img);
    int col = Grid.GetColumn(img);
}
```